# What color is the drummer's hair?

Tags: logical-deduction

Three friends - a cricketer named White, a footballer named Black and a drummer named Redhead met in a cafeteria.

"It is remarkable that one of us has white hair, another one has black hair and the third one has red hair, though no one's name gives the color of their hair" said the black haired person. "You are right" answered White.

> What color is the drummer's hair?

Comment: Why did you accept my edit, just to roll it back? I made changes to make this puzzle better, since it's not very good grammar as is.

Comment: @Riker I don't agree with some of your edits that's why I rolled back, but I agree with most of them so I made the edits. I am thankful to you to point out.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

White is not

> black haired since he responded back to the black haired person.

So White's hair can only be

> **red** since his hair is neither white nor black.

The rest is easy since we know what White hair color is

Black's hair color is

> **white** since Black cannot have black hair.

and Redhead's hair color is

> **black** which is the only color left.

Comment: Quicker would be the black haired person cannot be Black (same colour) or White (responded) so must be Redhead.

Comment: I agree with Orays answer above. If you are *really* picky, of course, one could argue that White *can* be the black haired person, if he frequently talks to himself and answers his own question. Then, and only then there would not be a way of determining the drummer's hair color. Of course this possibility could be easily removed if you slightly change the wording of the question ("the one other friend named White answers" or something).

Answer (score 0):

White's hair is

> not white,

since he agreed with the black-haired person. White's hair can also not be

> black,

because he is speaking with the black-haired person and each person has either black, white or red hair, according to the black-haired person's statement. So White's hair must be

> red.

The black-haired person's name cannot be

> Black,

because his hair is black, which means his name must be

> Redhead,

since he is talking to White. This means he is the drummer, which means the answer to the question "What color is the drummer's hair?" is:

> Black.

Comment: How does your answer add to the identical one already given? You should always look at existing answers before providing one of your own, to ensure you are not just adding a duplicate.

Comment: Yea I know. Initially I found the original answer to not be clear about actually answering the question: "What color is the drummer's hair?", but I realize that it can be inferred that Redhead is the drummer. So I guess my answer is a bit of a duplicate then. Should I remove it?

Answer (score 0):

```
Black   != Black hair   ==  White hair || Red hair
White   != White hair   ==  Black hair || Red hair
Redhead != Redh hair    ==  White hair || Black hair

(W || R) && (B || R) && (W || B)
```

Possible combinations:

```
1. WRB
2. RBW
```

Since White != Black hair (does not have black hair)

=> WRB => Readhead has Black hair